# trying to find best way to develop opengl es 2.0 in windows

Tags: windows, opengl-es-2.0

i like to develop games to android based on opengl es 2.0 , with the emulator its a apain 
is there any better way to develop opengl es 2.0 app on windows fast toolkit /engine ?
something that i can debug the code .
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of OpenGL ES 2.0 emulations on Windows to develop your application. Then majority of your rendering code will be same C/C++ code for Windows and for Android. Only platform specific stuff would be opening window, getting inputs (toches) and reading files.

Here are some of GLES2 emulators from different vendors:

- [Imgtec PowerVR](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp) - supports PVR texture compression
- [Qualcomm Ardeno](https://developer.qualcomm.com/develop/mobile-technologies/graphics-optimization-adreno/tools-and-resources) - supports ATITC texture compression
- [ARM Mali](http://www.malideveloper.com/developer-resources/tools/opengl-es-20-emulator.php)
- [Nvidia Tegra](http://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-resources-archive) - supports DXT texture compression
- [Google ANGLE](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) - supports DXT texture compression. Opensource! Used by Chrome & Firefox as WebGL backend.

I myself like and use Google ANGLE to develop my app on Windows. After that I can run app on Android without changing any of rendering code.

Comment: Thanks allot ! what do i will need to change if i use ANGLE ?

Comment: What do you mean - change? Regarding OpenGLES 2.0 - nothing, if you use only core functionality (not extensions). If you use some extensions then they differ between different devices and GLES implementations. If you ask about other stuff than OpenGLES 2.0, then you'll need to change everything - file loading, window opening, input (mouse/touch) receiving.

Comment: ok im beginner , if i like to develop in windows to OpenGLES 2.0 then 
to make minimum actions (in terms of development ) and compile it in android . what i need to do ?